# create a new IEnumerable based on other IEnumerable property values(basic LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder is there a way to get IEnumerable based on propertie values of another IEnumerable
for example:

```
class Person
{
    int Age{get;set;}
}

static void main()
{
  IEnumerable<Person> persons = GetPersons();
  IEnumerable<int> ages = persons.?(person => person.Age);
}
```

My question: Is there a method that can replace that question mark?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<int> ages = persons.Select(person => person.Age);
```